# Jasper Report Column Layout

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a Jasper Report that has a single detail section, and inside the detail section is a single field from the database that gets printed. So if my query returns 100 rows, I get 100 lines, which produces a report about 10 pages long, since 10 records fit on a page.

Is there a way I can print that field in columns, so that I can fit, say, 40 records on the page, instead of just 10? (By having 4 columns of 10)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure a multi-column report. If you are using iReport, right click in the *Report Inspector* on the report name and select *Page Format*. In the *Columns* Section increase Columns from `1` to `4`, if desired configure *Space* to define a distance between the columns. If you click on the report you can also choose the *Print order* in the *Properties* panel.

In the report designer you drag the field in the first column in the detail band.

the added properties in the JRXML are in the `<jasperreports ...` tag:

- `columnCount="4"`: 4 columns
- `printOrder="Horizontal"`: fill order is horizontal.

Attached the JRXML for further reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report8" language="groovy" columnCount="4" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="138" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5e2835cc-bc36-4f77-8631-08a8deaa28d7">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select 'A' as field]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="field" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="76707cdd-7dbe-477e-b3a4-38f9ba3bd003" x="0" y="0" width="136" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```